# code: 'ENOENT', message: 'No such file or directory' when using opencv.js in node-project

Tags: node.js, opencv, enoent

I'm using opencv.js for face detection. When I run this html file with the linked js files (opecv.js,utils.js) using a live server, it works.But,now when I copy the same files in my node project,and render this html page, I get the following error.

```
Uncaught
ErrnoError {node: undefined, errno: 2, code: 'ENOENT', message: 'No such file or directory', setErrno: ƒ, …}
code: "ENOENT"
errno: 2
message: "No such file or directory"
node: undefined
setErrno: ƒ (errno)
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 1
name: ""
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
[[FunctionLocation]]: opencv.js:24
[[Prototype]]: ƒ ()
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[4]
stack: "<generic error, no stack>"
[[Prototype]]: Error at Object.ensureErrnoError (http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/opencv.js:24:8492014) at Object.staticInit (http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/opencv.js:24:8492254) at http:
```

Comment: Are you able to access the file at `http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/opencv.js`? You need to to configure a seperate public folder wich contains all the js, css files.

Comment: Yes I can access, and it is in a separate public folder.